# Ionic gesture does not work with a prod build

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I use 3 gestures in my app :

```
<ion-content no-bounce (pan)="panGesture($event)" (tap)="tapGesture($event)" (press)="pressGesture($event)" style="height:100%;">
```

But when I build my app :

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

Only the last gesture (press) is called for all gestes !
I have the same problem with iOS :

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod
```

But when a use this command line before launch with Xcode to my iPhone :

```
ionic cordova prepare ios
```

All the gestures work.

But when I launch this command with android, the problem is not solved !!!

I compared the code "debug" with the code "prod" of main.js file and here is:

Debug:

```
<ion-content no-bounce (pan)="panGesture($event)" (tap)="tapGesture($event)" (press)="pressGesture($event)" style="height:100%;">
```

Prod :

```
function(n, t, e) {
            var l = !0,
                i = n.component;
            if ("pan" === t) {
                l = !1 !== i.panGesture(e) && l
            }
            if ("tap" === t) {
                l = !1 !== i.tapGesture(e) && l
            }
            if ("press" === t) {
                l = !1 !== i.pressGesture(e) && l
            }
            return l
        }
```

The t var is always equal to 'press'
If I replace the main.js and provider.js prod files with those of debug, it works.

I don't understand anything !

My config is :

- Ionic : 3.19.0
- Angular : 5.0.3

Comment: I just tested it on Android and it works (Ionic : 3.19.0, Angular : 5.0.3) : each gesture is called and detected correctly. Tested on actual device OnePlus 3T.

Comment: Sébastien Merci de. Dans mon application, sa ne fonctionne pas sur ma première page des onglets, mais ses travaux sur la page modale !!! And its works with a debug build not with a prod build.

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings anywhere? In cli when you build, or in the browser  console when debugging? I woud adive you create a new app with only the basic feature that you need to test and do step by step tests until you find the problem.